# looping in multidimensional array in angular js

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have an array like this

```
dataval =   [{"id":"1","emp_id":"27","amount":"555544"},{"id":"2","emp_id":"28","amount":"122"}]
```

I need to show a div only if `emp_id` does not exist in `dataval`. (Meaning `emp_id` can be 29 or 30 or anything except which is not in `dataval`).

My HTML is

```
<div ng-show="editId===p.id" ng-if="editId===p.id  ng-repeat="c in datavalue">
```

Comment: i hv used filter, grep, methods

Comment: Try this: http://plnkr.co/edit/hpMS02Oaxsb5cyfAuncI?p=preview

Comment: i need to show a div only if current emp_id is not in dataval.

Comment: Provided snippet is to demonstrate how it should be..And also correction of mistakes you made..You can implement your logic inside that...

Comment: i understand. I cant make it c.emp_id != p.id bcz it will show the div everytime the above condition fails inside loop.

Answer (score 1):

First, you're missing the closing `"` for you `ng-if` attribute.  This is probably messing you up in ways I'd rather not try guessing.

In situation like this, rather than trying to do anything non-trivial with ng directives in the View, I like to add a simple function to the Controller and do it in JavaScript.  Assuming you've defined `MyController as Ctlr`, ...

```
<div ng-if="!Ctlr.isInDataVal(c.emp_id)" ng-repeat="c in datavalue">
    ...
</div>
```

and in your Controller, you'd have something like ...

```
$scope.isInDataVal = function(emp_id) {
    // code returns true if emp_id is in dataval
}
```